# VertX eventbus.publish when running multiple instances

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient, vertx-eventbus

I'm beginning to realise VertX does its event bus publishing (eventbus.publish) fanning out to all instances of all verticle subscribed. But if I use eventbus.send for a specific address, that message gets delivered to a single instance of the targeted verticle. My requirement is the ability to publish a message and get it delivered to a **single instance** of all subscriber verticles.

Simply put, publish a message and make sure it received by all subscribers but only one instance of a given subscriber.

I can build up intermediate component to handle this, but I'm looking for more out of the box option to resolve this.

P.S. I tried this on cluster mode as well with one docker per verticle and results are same.

Comment: It's not supported but there are workarounds https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/2432